# Display two span elements one below other

Tags: html, css, angularjs, image, frontend

I want to display two span elements one below other. Here is my html code

```
<img class="profile-photo margin-0"
            data-ng-if="!question.isOpen"
            ng-src="{{question.profilePicId ? question.profilePicId : defaultUserAvatar}}"/>
<span ng-if="!question.isOpen" class="margin-left-10 title"
            ng-bind="question.title | translate"></span>
<span ng-if="!question.isOpen"
            ng-bind="getFirst100CharactersOfQuestion(question)"></span>
```

I tried using `<div>` tag `display: inline` and `float: left; clear: left` but it didn't work

Comment: try using `width:100%`

Comment: You could also use `HTML` with `<br />` to force a linebreak

Comment: `<br/>` shifts the line below image

Answer (score 0):

the default display of span is inline, add display: block

```css
.title {display:block}
```

```html
<span class="margin-left-10 title">hello</span>
<span>world</span>
```